# Webpack build error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, aurelia, package.json

**UPDATE TL;DR**
Thank to @sinan-bolel i now know the command

```
npm ls --depth=0
```

Which accurately display current *installed* npm packages. This got me half way. Now to distinguish between working and not working node_modules.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

How do i update my package.json to reflect all local installed packages from my project instead of whats in package.json?

Okay so webpack stopped building without a hint. 
This occures on desktop called PC_A.

PC_B has a working setup, running from Visual Studio Code ( with powershell ).
When PC_A site was destroyed my reaction was, ah easy. 
Just delete source from PC_A and update from SVN. This restored the files from before the bundling error and should be easy to get back up and running..

Just run npm install to reinstall all node_modules ( which are kept out of SVN ) and you're good to go right? no.

Webpack still generated the same build error after reinstalling with npm install. ( which to my knowledge reads the package.json and installs packages as specified )
Running npm run build generates in the following error:

```
node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\schema\validator.js:11
            throw new Error(ajv.errorsText());
    ^
Error: data['sourceMap'] should NOT have additional properties
```

Strange workaround:
I zipped my entire node_modules map and transfered it to PC_A and placed it correctly. Now webpack builds just fine.
So i think there must be something in node_modules on PC_B which fixes this problem, which is why i want to update my package.json. I do however NOT want to use npm upgrade --save(-dev) because this will update both local packages AND package.json to the LATEST version. I want to fill package.json with local version.

What i've tried:

```
npm upgrade --save & npm upgrade --save-dev
npm shrinkwrap ( looks promising but doesnt update package.json )
manual updating, tedious and not really scaleable )
npm ls --depth=0 ( works perfect, showing all installed packages! Now to find the culprit )
```

'Not working node_modules' npm ls --depth=0 produces:

```
aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.2 C:\brokenapp
+-- @easy-webpack/config-aurelia@2.2.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-babel@2.0.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-copy-files@1.1.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-css@2.5.0
+-- @easy-webpack/config-env-development@2.1.6
+-- @easy-webpack/config-env-production@2.2.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-external-source-maps@2.0.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-fonts-and-images@1.2.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html@2.1.1
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-bluebird@1.3.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-jquery@1.4.1
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-regenerator@1.3.0
+-- @easy-webpack/config-html@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-json@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-source-map-support@1.0.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-test-coverage-istanbul@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-typescript@2.1.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-uglify@2.2.3
+-- @easy-webpack/core@1.4.5
+-- @types/bluebird@2.0.31
+-- @types/d3@4.4.0
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.43
+-- @types/leaflet@1.0.41
+-- @types/turf@3.5.32
+-- @types/whatwg-fetch@0.0.27
+-- aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-dialog@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1
+-- aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.1
+-- aurelia-framework@1.0.7
+-- aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-loader-webpack@1.0.3
+-- aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1
+-- aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0
+-- aurelia-router@1.0.7
+-- aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-templating-resources@1.1.1
+-- aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-tools@0.2.4
+-- babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.22.0
+-- babel-preset-es2015-loose@7.0.0
+-- babel-preset-es2015-loose-native-modules@1.0.0
+-- babel-preset-stage-1@6.22.0
+-- babel-register@6.23.0
+-- bluebird@3.4.6
+-- bootstrap@3.3.7
+-- concurrently@2.2.0
+-- cross-env@2.0.1
+-- d3@4.3.0
+-- d3-tile@0.0.3
+-- font-awesome@4.7.0
+-- http-server@0.9.0
+-- isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1
+-- jasmine-core@2.5.2
+-- jquery@3.1.1
+-- karma@1.5.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@1.0.1
+-- karma-coverage@1.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.0
+-- karma-mocha-reporter@2.2.2
+-- karma-remap-istanbul@0.1.1
+-- karma-sourcemap-loader@0.3.7
+-- karma-webpack@1.8.1
+-- leaflet@1.0.1
+-- lodash@4.16.6
+-- moment@2.15.2
+-- protractor@4.0.14
+-- rimraf@2.6.1
+-- topojson@2.2.0
+-- ts-node@1.7.3
+-- turf@3.0.14
+-- typescript@2.1.1
+-- wait-on@1.5.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.22
`-- webpack-dev-server@2.4.1

npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^2.2.0, required by webpack-dev-server@2.4.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^2.2.0, required by extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0
```

'Working node_modules' npm ls --depth=0 produces:

```
aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.2 C:\app
+-- @easy-webpack/config-aurelia@2.2.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-babel@2.0.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-copy-files@1.1.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-css@2.5.0
+-- @easy-webpack/config-env-development@2.1.6
+-- @easy-webpack/config-env-production@2.2.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-external-source-maps@2.0.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-fonts-and-images@1.2.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html@2.1.1
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-bluebird@1.3.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-jquery@1.4.1
+-- @easy-webpack/config-global-regenerator@1.3.0
+-- @easy-webpack/config-html@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-json@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-source-map-support@1.0.2
+-- @easy-webpack/config-test-coverage-istanbul@2.0.3
+-- @easy-webpack/config-typescript@2.1.4
+-- @easy-webpack/config-uglify@2.2.3
+-- @easy-webpack/core@1.4.5
+-- @types/bluebird@2.0.31
+-- @types/d3@4.4.0
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.41
+-- @types/leaflet@1.0.41
+-- @types/turf@3.5.32
+-- @types/whatwg-fetch@0.0.27
+-- aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-dialog@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1
+-- aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.1
+-- aurelia-framework@1.0.7
+-- aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-loader-webpack@1.0.3
+-- aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1
+-- aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0
+-- aurelia-router@1.0.7
+-- aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-templating-resources@1.1.1
+-- aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0
+-- aurelia-tools@0.2.4
+-- babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.22.0
+-- babel-preset-es2015-loose@7.0.0
+-- babel-preset-es2015-loose-native-modules@1.0.0
+-- babel-preset-stage-1@6.22.0
+-- babel-register@6.22.0
+-- bluebird@3.4.6
+-- bootstrap@3.3.7
+-- concurrently@2.2.0
+-- cross-env@2.0.1
+-- d3@4.3.0
+-- d3-tile@0.0.3
+-- font-awesome@4.7.0
+-- http-server@0.9.0
+-- isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1
+-- jasmine-core@2.5.2
+-- jquery@3.1.1
+-- karma@1.4.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@1.0.1
+-- karma-coverage@1.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.0
+-- karma-mocha-reporter@2.2.2
+-- karma-remap-istanbul@0.1.1
+-- karma-sourcemap-loader@0.3.7
+-- karma-webpack@1.8.1
+-- leaflet@1.0.1
+-- lodash@4.16.6
+-- moment@2.15.2
+-- protractor@4.0.14
+-- rimraf@2.5.4
+-- topojson@2.2.0
+-- ts-node@1.7.3
+-- turf@3.0.14
+-- typescript@2.1.1
+-- wait-on@1.5.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.22
`-- webpack-dev-server@2.2.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^2.2.0, required by webpack-dev-server@2.2.0
npm ERR! extraneous: moment@2.15.1 C:\app\node_modules\wait-on\node_modules\moment
```

So how do i distinguish between not working and working to locate the package(s) that are causing the error?

Comment: You can run `npm ls --depth=0` on PC_A/B and compare the versions of the packages listed to those specified in package.json and to each other. Could you please add a Gist of your package.json and the output of `npm ls`?

Comment: wil try this monday first thing @SinanBolel

Comment: sounds good, thanks!

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you. Will keep you posted if this find the problematic package(s) @sinanbolel

Comment: Awesome @DGRFDSGN I'm happy to hear you've made progress, and looking forward to seeing if we can resolve the issue. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: I'm going to check versions with a easy js function, this got me there 90%, let plain old javascript get me there a 100%. Thanks for the help! Do you want to shoot it as a solution? @SinanBolel

Comment: Sure! I'll add it shortly :)

Comment: One more thing: I always use exact versions in package.json. When I install anything, I remove the `^` to make sure the version installed on any machine is the version specified in package.json. This makes updates painful, however, thankfully theres `npm-check-updates`. Install it globally and you can run `ncu` in a project directory to see what updates are available

Comment: agreed, i have also removed all ^ as a tip from another dev-force. Hopefully i will pinpoint the package that caused the build error in the first place, because a error that disappears without fixing it will come back with his friends :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `npm ls --depth=0` to list the installed packages for a project.

Run it on PC_A and PC_B, then compare the versions of the packages listed on both machines to those specified in package.json. That will allow you to find any discrepancies.

You can also lock packages to exact versions by removing `^`, `>=`, etc. from version numbers in package.json dependencies to ensure that the exact version specified in the package.json file is the one that gets installed.

Refer to the [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) documentation for more info on versioning standards.

Comment: i have added the result of both pc's to my original question, prehaps you can help me find the culprit?

Comment: I'd suggest putting the lists side by side to find the differences... like the one in **the first line**.

Comment: Yes thats what i have done, except the differences are as following: PC_A forinstance gulp v. 1.0.0 and PC_B gulp v^2.0.0, ^ => make it hard to deceifer the versions and come up with which one 'brakes' install on a clean setup. Hardcoding all version numbers did not resolve this. pounding a wall so to speak :/

Comment: @DGRFDSGN were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No, we ended up abandoning the project altogether, but mostly because of funding problems in the team, im sure the package-version-problem could be solved by check versions with npm @sinan-bolel sidenote: this was in a time when nor me, or really anyone in my team was adequate verbose in node.js, the project was originally set up by a full-stack guru who left us holding the ropes. Lesson learned share all knowledge between collegues